# Nest + Fastify + fasity-next + TypeOrm cannot find next() function

Tags: javascript, next.js, nestjs, typeorm, fastify

I am trying to initialize Nest with Fastify and Next using the fastify-next plugin, everything was okay until I integrated TypeOrm (MongoDB). When Nest loads the AppModule it throws an error that says the `.next()` function is not found in the `fastify` instance after the `fastify-next` plugin is initialized.

Code

```
// main.ts
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestFastifyApplication>(
    AppModule,
    new FastifyAdapter(),
  );

  await app.init();

  const configService = app.get<ConfigService<IConfigTypes>>(ConfigService);
  const appConfig = configService.get<IAppConfig>('app');

  const fastify = await app.register(fastifyNext, {
    dev: appConfig.isDev,
    dir: appConfig.clientPath,
  });

  fastify.after(() => {
    appConfig.staticRoutes.forEach((page) => fastify.next(page));
  });

  await app.listen(appConfig.port);
  Logger.log(` Server is running on port ${appConfig.port}`, 'Bootstrap');
}
bootstrap();
```

```
// app.module.ts
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      validate,
      isGlobal: true,
      cache: true,
      load: [appConfig, shopifyConfig, databaseConfig],
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      useFactory: (configService: ConfigService<IConfigTypes>) => {
        const dbConfig = configService.get<IDatabaseConfig>('database');
        const { type, host, base, user, pass } = dbConfig;

        let url = 'mongodb+srv://';
        url += `${user}:${pass}@${host}/${base}`;
        url += '?retryWrites=true&w=majority';

        return {
          type,
          url,
          entities: [join(__dirname, '**/**.entity{.ts,.js}')],
          synchronize: true,
          useNewUrlParser: true,
          logging: true,
        };
      },
      inject: [ConfigService],
    }),
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Console with Error:

```
[8:45:52 AM] File change detected. Starting incremental compilation...

[8:45:52 AM] Found 0 errors. Watching for file changes.

[Nest] 26331  - 08/23/2021, 8:45:53 AM     LOG [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
[Nest] 26331  - 08/23/2021, 8:45:53 AM     LOG [InstanceLoader] AppModule dependencies initialized +26ms
[Nest] 26331  - 08/23/2021, 8:45:53 AM     LOG [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 26331  - 08/23/2021, 8:45:53 AM     LOG [InstanceLoader] ConfigHostModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 26331  - 08/23/2021, 8:45:53 AM     LOG [InstanceLoader] ConfigModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 26331  - 08/23/2021, 8:45:53 AM     LOG [InstanceLoader] ConfigModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 26331  - 08/23/2021, 8:45:55 AM     LOG [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmCoreModule dependencies initialized +2361ms
[Nest] 26331  - 08/23/2021, 8:45:55 AM     LOG [NestApplication] Nest application successfully started +5ms

/dir/to/project/node_modules/avvio/boot.js:533
      res = func()
            ^
TypeError: fastify.next is not a function
    at /dir/to/project/src/server/main.ts:30:54 ===> appConfig.staticRoutes.forEach((page) => fastify.next(page));
```

My temporary solution is to wait until the `.next()` function becomes available in the `fastify` instance and then run the code. But I don't think that this is the correct way of solving this issue.

Code:

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestFastifyApplication>(
    AppModule,
    new FastifyAdapter(),
  );

  await app.init();

  const configService = app.get<ConfigService<IConfigTypes>>(ConfigService);
  const appConfig = configService.get<IAppConfig>('app');

  const fastify = await app.register(fastifyNext, {
    dev: appConfig.isDev,
    dir: appConfig.clientPath,
  });

  await new Promise((res) => {
    const launch = async () => {
      if (!fastify.next) {
        setTimeout(launch, 200);
        return;
      }

      appConfig.staticRoutes.forEach((page) => fastify.next(page));
      await app.listen(appConfig.port);
      Logger.log(` Server is running on port ${appConfig.port}`, 'Bootstrap');
      res(null);
    };

    launch();
  });
}
bootstrap();
```

If I remove `TypeOrmModule` from `AppModule` the error disappears, I think the error is caused by the async loading of the Module `forRootAsync`.

Does anyone have any idea on how to fix it? If you know the better solution to solving this issue, please help me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that I found is to get FastifyInstance from Nest.js HTTPAdapter and use that instance to register the plugin. Also, I used a promise to wait until fastify registers the plugin and then listen to the port (start the app).

```js
  await app.init();

  const configService = app.get<ConfigService<IConfigTypes>>(ConfigService);
  const appConfig = configService.get<IAppConfig>('app');
  const fastify = app.getHttpAdapter().getInstance() as FastifyInstance;

  await new Promise((resolve) => {
    fastify
      .register(fastifyNext, {
        dev: appConfig.isDev,
        dir: appConfig.clientPath,
      })
      .after(async () => {
        appConfig.staticRoutes.forEach((route) => fastify.next(route));
        resolve(null);
      });
  });

  await app.listen(appConfig.port);
  Logger.log(` Server is running on port ${appConfig.port}`, 'Bootstrap');
```